# Got an error trying to run a nblockchain made in C#

Tags: c#, blockchain, c#-2.0

I wanted to give making a blockchain a try so I looked for resources for making a blockchain in C#.
I cam across a project called Nblockchain that is supposed to aid with that.

https://github.com/danielgerlag/NBlockchain

Anyways I tried running it and while it did run it gave me some errors.

```
NBlockchain.Services.BlockchainNode:Information: Requesting head block
The thread 0x56b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7464 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
NBlockchain.Services.BlockMiner:Information: Mining genesis block
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.30\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.30\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
NBlockchain.Services.PeerDiscovery.MulticastDiscovery:Information: Discovering peers
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
NBlockchain.Services.PeerDiscovery.MulticastDiscovery:Error: Error joining multicast - Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me what those errors mean and how to fix them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off looking up simpler creations of blockchains. I have a very basic intro to blockchains and 3 lessons you can go over. Once you understand that you can probably start diving a bit more into the more complex projects.

https://github.com/mathis1337/Basic-Blockchain-Tutorial

They were all done in C# too

The error you are receiving above is most likely due to only running one peer. Blockschains in development generally require to running peers to move beyond the genesis block you created.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the hostility from other people but thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck in your journey.